# How do I fix an error: expected an indented block

Tags: python-3.x, indentation

I keep getting this error message that says `expected an indent block`.
The shell highlights the bold spot as the error. Any suggestions on how I fix it? 
I am just a beginner so any and all help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

```
from random import *

s = choice( [ 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors' ])

def rps( ):
""" runs a game of Rock Paper Scissors between the program and the user by returning the user's choice and the program's choice and signaling a winner
    input: the user's choice which is one of three responses in the game Rock-Paper- Scissors - all are a string of letters
    """

print ('rps( )')
print ('Welcome to a game of Rock Paper Scissors!')
print ('I just made my choice.')
print ('I promise no cheating this time!')
r = input('Now you choose rock, paper, or scissors!')       
print
```

> **if r == 'paper':**

```
       print ('You chose paper.')
       if s == 'scissors':
              print ('I chose scissors. Haha, I win fair and square!')
       elif s == 'rock':
              print ("I chose rock. Maybe I'll have better luck next time...")
       elif s == 'paper':
              print ('We need a rematch!')

elif r == 'scissors':
       print ('You chose scissors.')
       if s == 'rock':
              print ('I chose rock. Haha, I win fair and square!')
       elif s == 'paper':
              print ("I chose paper. Maybe I'll have better luck next time...")
       elif s == 'scissors':
              print ('We need a rematch!')



elif r =='rock':
       print ('You chose rock.')
       if s == 'paper':
              print ('I chose paper. Haha, I win fair and square!')
       elif s == 'scissors':
              print ("I chose scissors. Maybe I'll have better luck next time...")
       elif s == 'rock':
              print ('We need a rematch!'

else:
       print ("Don't you know the rules? Choose rock, paper or scissors!")
```

Comment: What line is the error?

Comment: I think it should be fixed now, the formatting.

Comment: I think I indented correctly after that but it keeps giving me the error. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten a `')'` at the end of the 3rd `elif`, it just says `print ('We need a rematch!'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... all of this is really confused.

First of all, there is nothing inside the function `rps()` except for a comment. This is how you define a function:

```
def hi_im_a_function():
    hi im inside the function

hi, im not inside the function.

hi_im_a_function()
```

^calling the function

In fact, that whole function appears to be obsolete. I don't know what you were trying to accomplish with that `print('rps()')` thing, but it isn't doing anything. I suggest you drop it.

The error is coming from that random floating `print` on the line right before the error. The error is landing on the `if r == paper` line because that is where the compiler first feels the effects of the error you set in the line before it.

As before, I don't know what you were trying to do there, but that statement has no purpose there. Delete it.

Fix those errors, and it should work like a charm.

Comment: I wanted to print the name of the function and the information at the beginning. I know it doesn't have an input in the rps() so that why the () are empty but are you saying I need to indent everything after that in order for it to be part of the function?

Comment: yes. it all needs to be indented. it looks like you did it right in your newest answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed it!

from random import *

s = choice( [ 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors' ])

def rps( ):
       """ runs a game of Rock Paper Scissors between the program and the user by returning the user's choice and the program's choice and signaling a winner
          Technically this function has no inputs and no return value; the function is an interaction between the user and the program
       """

```
   print ('Welcome to a game of Rock Paper Scissors!')
   print ('I just made my choice.')
   print ('I promise no cheating this time!')
   r = input('Now you choose rock, paper, or scissors!')

   if r == 'paper':
          print ('You chose paper.')
          if s == 'scissors':
                 print ('I chose scissors. Haha, I win fair and square!')
          elif s == 'rock':
                 print ("I chose rock. Maybe I'll have better luck next time...")
          elif s == 'paper':
                 print ('We need a rematch!')

   elif r == 'scissors':
          print ('You chose scissors.')
          if s == 'rock':
                 print ('I chose rock. Haha, I win fair and square!')
          elif s == 'paper':
                 print ("I chose paper. Maybe I'll have better luck next time...")
          elif s == 'scissors':
                 print ('We need a rematch!')



   elif r =='rock':
          print ('You chose rock.')
          if s == 'paper':
                 print ('I chose paper. Haha, I win fair and square!')
          elif s == 'scissors':
                 print ("I chose scissors. Maybe I'll have better luck next time...")
          elif s == 'rock':
                 print ('We need a rematch!')

   else:
          print ("Don't you know the rules? Choose rock, paper or scissors!")
```

Comment: great! now would you mind selecting my answer as the correct one so i can has reputation? :D